# How to make a Dr Strange portal

Tags: particles

How would I be able to make the the sling ring portal. The best I have been able to  to looks quite bad and I don't know what else to do.
[image]

The file [image]

Comment: Increasing the Motion Blur from 0.5 to 1.0 made a big difference. Having watched Infinity war just a few days ago, I would say the rotation is too slow and it is to symmetrical. I also recall small amounts of blue flecks.

Comment: How Would I be able to add the adjustments you have mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Portal]

There are three core ideas to recreate the portal VFX from Dr. Strange:

1. Motion blur
2. Rotating the particle emitter
3. Asymmetry in the particle emission

The look of flying sparks can be achieved by using motion blur in combination with an emissive material for the particles. The particle emitter should be a circular mesh. It's also important how the particles are emitted, since in the movie they fly away from the circle in a tangential direction while seemingly unaffected by gravity. This can be achieved by spinning the emitter, setting the normal velocity to zero, setting the tangential velocity of the particles to a suitable value and deactivating gravity. A more subtle effect in the movie is that even when the portal is fully open the emission intensity and particle distribution wobbles slightly. This can be achieved by removing segments from the circular particle emitter. The amount of wobble depends on the speed of the emitter's rotation, lower speed results in more wobble.

[image: Screenshot]

You can download the project by clicking on the link below:

[image]

A quick breakdown of how a scene with the portal was filmed for the movie and the result with the added VFX can be seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8YxF4yMDSkw&feature=youtu.be&t=86).

Comment: For the different particles I can just go into the shader for the instanced object and use particle info and colour ramp to get variation in the particles right?

Comment: @Yohello1 Correct. For instance you could use the particle age to change to a different color or reduce the strength of the emission. The shader in my example is very basic.

Comment: @rjp Then I would have to render in cycles I tried some thing like that some time ago but it would inly show different colour in cycles.